# How to calculate maximum between two or more lists element by element and also the index corresponding to the maximum element?

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am looking for a function say f such that for example

f[{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2}] will give {Max[a1,a2],Max[b1,b2],Max[c1,c2]}

and also a function g say such that

g[{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}},{{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, d3}}] will give
{Max[a1, b1, c1, d1], Max[a2, b2, c2, d2], Max[a3, b3, c3, d3]}.

and a function h such that

h[{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2}] will give the indices of the maximal elements in the matrix {{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2}}.

Similarly for two or more matrices, h[{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}},{{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, d3}}]

I can do this by creating a new table element by element using if or Which statements but I don't want to re-invent the wheel, is there a simpler way to do that ?

All ideas grately appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**

```
a = {a1, b1, c1};
b = {a2, b2, c2};

MapThread[Max, {a, b}]
```

{Max[a1, a2], Max[b1, b2], Max[c1, c2]}

**2.**

```
ar = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, d3}};

MapThread[Max, Flatten[ar, 1]]
```

{Max[a1, b1, c1, d1], Max[a2, b2, c2, d2], Max[a3, b3, c3, d3]}

**3.**

```
br = {{20, 30, 10}, {10, 20, 40}};

PositionLargest /@ br
```

{{2}, {3}}

**4.**

```
cr = {{{20, 30, 10}, {10, 20, 40}}, {{5, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}};

Map[PositionLargest, cr, {2}]
```

{{{2}, {3}}, {{1}, {3}}}

**5.**

If `PositionLargest` isn't available (Versions prior to 13.2):

```
Flatten[Position[#, Max[#]] &[#] & /@ br, 1]
```

{{2}, {3}}

```
Join @@@ Map[Position[#, Max[#]] &[#] &, cr, {2}]
```

{{{2}, {3}}, {{1}, {3}}}

**6.**

All of these functions can easily be "personalized", for example:

```
Clear @ h

h[dt_] := Flatten[Position[#, Max[#]] &[#] & /@ dt, 1]

h[{{20, 30, 10}, {10, 20, 40}}]
```

{{2}, {3}}

Comment: That's great! But what to do with the maximal indices?

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Extract the corresponding elements?

Comment: PositionLargest is not available in version 8 which is the one that I have.

Comment: Yes find the position of the maximal elements. This is the final statement of the notebook.

Comment: Please see the updates

Comment: Yes I saw the updates, thanks! Now how do I mark your answer as the best solution?

Comment: You have to click the checkmark at the top left of my answer

Comment: I just did that

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :)